# Problem with making a comma separated dataset imported as separate columns

Tags: r, csv, import, dataset

there is a dateset in .csv foramt which is comma separeted. i tried to use different methods to import it like read.csv and read.table and i used the " , " optoion, yet when i View the dataset, it's only 2 column. is there a way to import this dataset in a way that has like 13 separate columns with distinct headings?

dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/sulianova/cardiovascular-disease-dataset

Comment: Share essential parts of your code you have tried, and also a reproducible example of your dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. Go to import Dataset (picture)
2. Press From Text(readr)
3. Browse your file location and change Delimitertyp to Semicolon.
4. The code is in the last picture bottom right.
   [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: any solution for the Age column? seems like numbers are piling up on each other.

Comment: ? What do you mean by pilling up. Picture?

Answer (score 1):

I did simply by changing the `sep`

```
df <- read.csv('cardio_train.csv', sep = ';')
head(df)

  id   age gender height weight ap_hi ap_lo cholesterol gluc smoke alco active cardio
1  0 18393      2    168     62   110    80           1    1     0    0      1      0
2  1 20228      1    156     85   140    90           3    1     0    0      1      1
3  2 18857      1    165     64   130    70           3    1     0    0      0      1
4  3 17623      2    169     82   150   100           1    1     0    0      1      1
5  4 17474      1    156     56   100    60           1    1     0    0      0      0
6  8 21914      1    151     67   120    80           2    2     0    0      0      0
```

Comment: any solution for the age column? number are ranges i guess, but they are mixed now.

Comment: @BenyaminHamidekhoo, This is as per the data available in csv.  For new questions, please post another question.